# Petapoco: How to databind gridview using join from two tables?

Tags: petapoco

I dont want to do using a custom class.

```
var q = db.Query<dynamic>(query); //This does not work
```

query has joins and custom created columns from multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the PetaPoco.cs "ExecuteReader" method to see if it looks something like this(see code below):

my file did not have any code in the function so I model it after Execute scalar method.
this will return a generic DataTable that is perfectly bindable to datagrid.
however keep in mind that to make any changes to the data you will need to implement 
your own CRUD methods as the resulting DataTable is readonly.

```
    //Execute Reader
        public DataTable ExecuteReader(string sql, params object[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenSharedConnection();
                try
                {
                    using (var cmd = CreateCommand(_sharedConnection, sql, args))
                    {
                        var val = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        OnExecutedCommand(cmd);
                        var dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(val);
                        return dt; //(T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseSharedConnection();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                OnException(x);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public DataTable ExecuteReader(Sql sql)
        {
            return ExecuteReader(sql.SQL, sql.Arguments);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that contains the fields from the two tables you want to display in the grid.
Populate your query with a SQL statement that joins the tables and returns the columns you need.
Then

```
var q=db.Query<YourClassName>.Query(query)
```

should work.

Comment: is it possible to do this without creating a custom class? because for all the datagrids im using it has joins.

Comment: In theory, yes - I've used Dynamic Linq to do this - but you would have to find a Datagrid that could understand and bind to dynamic objects. Personally I think it's perfectly fine to define a class that represents data as you need to show it on screen.

Comment: @rickalous thanks for the response. Think about this. When we use a command object and a stored proc that has several joins. You bind to a datagrid and it actually works. When it can be done this way, why not petapoco handle it?

Comment: @VivekChandraprakash Because it's possible that PetaPoco designed it this way; when you use Command, you use a DataSet or DataTable, which is a dynamic structure that can support that flexibility.  I haven't seen anything else within the documentation that says it does support returning an anonymous type; it's hard to dynamically build something that returns an anonymous type; anonymous types are usually for a fixed resultset, not a dynamic, generic one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database view, and then the T4 templates will automatically generate the class for that. You need to add

```
IncludeViews = true;
```

to Database.tt